# PHP how to query all the newest products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

what im trying to do is to make a query to get all the lastest new products, Im using woocommerce Plugin.
newest products are products that been created in the last 30 days.
i have tried to get this by meta_query, but could not find the right key, or maybe it is the worng way.

```
$args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 7,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms'         => $terms,
                    'operator'      => 'IN'
                )),
                    'meta_query'     => array(
                        array( // Simple products type
                            'key'           => '[ tried a key like '_sale_price' which give you products onsale]',
                            'value'         => 0,
                            'compare'       => '>',
                            'type'          => 'numeric'
                        ),
                    ),
            );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

any suggestion please?

Comment: You need to do a date_query rather than a meta_query

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use 'meta query' because the product create date contains in the 'post' table not in the 'post meta'. You have to try use 'date_query'. Something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 7,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'    => array(
                'year'  => 2021,
                'month' => 3,
                'day'   => 9,
            ),
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Alexandr i needed it dynamic so i changed it a bit, this way the date is updated all the time, and its works :)

```
$args = array(
                'post_type'      => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => 7,
                'date_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'after'    => array(
                            'year'  => date("Y"),
                            'month' => date('n')-1,
                            'day'   => date('d'),
                        ),
                        'inclusive' => true,
                    ),
                ),
                
            );
```

this way im getting the latest new products in the past 1 mount